# Convert VML graphic to bitmap on the ASP.NET server

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, bitmap, raphael, vector-graphics

I'm using **[RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html)**. The **browser renders a chart** for me (which is **in VML** as all my users are on IE). I want the user to be able to save this image and share it normally eg paste into an email, into powerpoint, into a document etc etc.

Problem is not many things can render VML. I can easily get the VML markup describing the image back to the server. All I want to do **is convert it** to some kind of more universal format eg **PNG, BMP, GIFF, whatever** which I can then allow the user to download.

I've seen lots of people struggling with this. I would have thought the seeing as **VML is Microsoft's** proprietary SVG format they might have **at least provided facilities** within their own languages (C#,VB.net) **to convert VML to bitmaps**.

Anyone know how?

(Incidentally I **can't use PHP** - I've seen a lot of people attempting to solve this with a PHP based solution)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Internet Explorer ActiveX control and screenshotting techniques to achieve this. See the open source tool [IECapt](http://iecapt.sourceforge.net/) as an example.

You could also evaluate whether a cloud service like [Litmus API](http://litmus.com/api) could be used.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer, I hadn't come across IECapt. It says it has "experimental support for Enhanced Metafile vector graphic output" but do you know if that will encompass VML output? As for the cloud I can't go down that route as I'm developing on a corporate intranet and there would be all sorts of issues around confidentiality/firewalls etc...

Comment: What you are looking for is VML input. The WMF output means that you can save a web page as WMF vector graphics. Due to its scalable nature, WMF might be more suitable to e.g. printing than PNG.

Comment: I haven't got this working yet but it looks like the only way to go! Thanks.