# Inkscape not handling SVG properly from command line

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, png, inkscape

This is a follow up to my [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913725/converting-rvml-to-svg-using-xslt-in-c) posted previously.

My .NET application can now successfully convert a VML file to SVG, using the XSLT provided by [VectorConverter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vectorconverter/) and the .NET [XslTransform class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltransform(v=vs.71).aspx).

For all browsers except IE, the [Inkscape command line utility](http://inkscape.modevia.com/inkscape-man.html) works perfectly well.  I get a nice PNG image of my entire SVG drawing.  However with IE, the output PNG is only of a very small portion of the input SVG.  Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: I've never seen this. Could you link to example SVG and PNG files?

Comment: @echo-flow, thanks for your comment but I have managed to work around this issue for the time being - see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that code output by the VML --> SVG transformation was missing out the dimensions in the XML tag, as in:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="xx" height="yy"> 
</svg>
```

I got around it by reading the file back, adding the width and height attributes and then re-writing the file.  It's not a great solution but it works for the time being, I've still not managed to find the underlying issue - if I do I will post it back here.