# rvml To svg convert using php 5.3

Tags: php, svg, vml

I am using raphael.js which generate rvml on IE. what i want is to convert this rvml to svg so that it can make png images for that svg.

Answer (score 0):

This page has solution using C# but still you can utilize it by porting the regex logic to PHP native form.

[Converting RVML to SVG using XSLT in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913725/converting-rvml-to-svg-using-xslt-in-c-sharp)

hope it helps u out.